# How to keep ONLY duplicated values in Pandas Dataframe?

Tags: pandas, duplicates, unique

I need to drop the feature 'county' that is unique to every row and therefore have no value in my machine learning process.

However, the below code is not removing the unique values, for just county, as they are still in my dataset? HELP.

```
# counting unique values
n = len(pd.unique(data['county']))
  
print("No.of.unique values :", 
      n)


data[data.groupby('county')['county'].transform('size') > 1]
data
```

| state | county |
| --- | --- |
| AL | Barbour County |
| AL | Barbour County |
| WY | Sweetwater County |

I also tried

```
data = data[data.duplicated(subset=['county'], keep=False)]
```

no luck.

Comment: You want to remove rows where each of their county values only appear once across all rows?

Comment: Can you provide an explicit minimal input and the matching expected output?

Answer (score 2):

Both snippets that you posted should be removing the rows with Unique values for county

```
data[data.groupby('county')['county'].transform('size') > 1]
```

I would make a small correction to your snippet by assigning the variable:

```
non_unique_data = data[data.groupby('county')['county'].transform('size') > 1]
```

Same with your second snippet.

```
non_unique_data = data[data.duplicated(subset=['county'], keep=False)]
```

Now when you check your variable value for

```
non_unique_data
```

You'll see that it's only kept the data with duplicate values in `county`

I think you're having issues because you're assigning your result to the original dataframe.